# How to parse a simple JSON return form Facebook API in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, facebook

I know this question has been repeated many times. But I am getting error and I almost tried all answers and solutions.

Here is JSON:

```
 (
        {
        id = 879453454392996;
        name = "Test1 test1";
    },
        {
        id = 139435345344975;
        name = "Test2 test2";
    }
)
```

I get this JSON in this way:

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me/friends"
                                                               parameters:nil];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
{
    if (!error) {



          NSLog(@"result== %@",result[@"data"]);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error in reading friend list");
    }
}];
```

This works fine so far. 
Now I want to put these ids inside one array. I have imported:

```
#import <Foundation/NSJSONSerialization.h>
```

I am not using any other framework.

**EDIT**

I tried some of the answers:

```
NSLog(@"result== %@",result[@"data"]);
```

Prints:

```
 (
        {
        id = 879453454392996;
        name = "Test1 test1";
    },
        {
        id = 139435345344975;
        name = "Test2 test2";
    }
)

NSLog(@"name is %@", [result objectForKey:@"name"]);
```

retun `name is (null)`.

```
NSLog(@"name is %@", [result[@"data"] objectForKey:@"name"]);
```

returns:

```
-[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17426d480
2015-09-23 15:11:35.281 myapp[1257:181878] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17426d480'
```

**Edit 2**

OUTPUT FOR:

```
NSLog(@"result== %@",result);


result== {
    data =     (
                {
            id = 8795555555792996;
            name = "TEST TEST";
        },
                {
            id = 139051444474975;
            name = "TEST2 TEST2";
        }
    );
    paging =     {
        next = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/743447008322/friends?format=json&access_token=CAAWScq3N1MCOvayeO1ocBVMzK9WiYDDavjb5nOpDnUocpzTEqDCJ2Ew8X3lLopTJ7EuidUNZChTCebTAULnGq2342RNYVcKmnoo43ssJtr6G0TQQLOTs2kkHtKL4yqu4U37GeyygPe1ZBL59I3MiEV6ju8z4bZAMUxudKRhBJFBLRJFBWZBoyHiZAOozE5oZAncZAjXf04dQEW0EZCXTa&limit=25&offset=25&__after_id=enc_AdBepNUFZAj3OmbSQddddUZCzUtPzeDuYZCO33rkZCfAZBqSkBjwrqRgvPhYEkzkVcuWu46NFLSKN5psNNsR5cIAncWg";
    };
    summary =     {
        "total_count" = 7;
    };
}
```

Comment: It looks like `result` is already converted into an `NSDictionary`. There's no need for `NSJSONSerialization`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get id by:

```
NSArray * arrData = result[@"data"];
for (NSDictionary * dict in arrData)
{
  NSString * strID = dict[@"id"];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I access the fields in the json. Like id for each element?

Comment: //// for example, get email of user
        //// NSString * strEmail = result[@"email"]; you can see I write an example for email.

Comment: Can you post the result of this line `NSLog(@"result: %@",result);` ? I wonder why you can get ` (
        {
        id = 879453454392996;
        name = "Test1 test1";
    },
        {
        id = 139435345344975;
        name = "Test2 test2";
    }
)`

Comment: But I need to know "id" for each element. So I need a for loop and need to know how many elements is inside result to read each id.

Comment: Thanks mate. you're a life saver.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to parse the response. It's already parsed for you.

Comment: Read the error. `result` is an `NSDictionary`, not `NSArray`.

Comment: @rmaddy I saw that but his parsed JSON is an array of dictionaries. Maybe OP forgot to paste full string with surrounding curly braces?